# Scope image URL not updated & showing in view (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to retrieve an image link from Google Firebase that is put in a scope variable. This works when I perform the retrieval of the URL in an action using a different controller before this one loads it. However, when retrieving it in this controller, my div somehow doesn't want to display the image. I've checked with a simple ng-bind whether the scope variable is updated, and it is. However, the picture div in the view stays empty. Does anyone know how I can get my view to display the image?

Controller:

```
$scope.profilepicture = null;

var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var path = "profilepictures/" + userFactory.getUser().uid + "/profilepicture";
var profilePicRef = storageRef.child(path);

profilePicRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.profilepicture = url;
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-click="getImage()" ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url({{profilepicture}})'}" style="width:100px; etc...></div>
```

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle (with some example Firebase account)?

Comment: I don't really think the solution should be found there. The URL is retrieved and is correct. It only isn't updating the div to find the image anymore, so I'm wondering how I can get my div element to reload and reflect my scope variable change.

Comment: I don't think it neither, jut would like to have something to play with a little bit because I don't have any idea what's wrong right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url(' + profilepicture + ')'}"
```

I've just found the issue. The ng-style url needed to be written like this: ' + value + '

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this by removing braces from there, but just make sure you are getting a right value of profilepicture.

```
<div ng-click="getImage()" ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url(profilepicture)'}" style="width:100px; etc...></div>
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work either sadly. The '{{}}' worked in my previous implementation as well where the url was stored in a factory.